# Return Status of first command before Pipe in ksh

Tags: shell, return, pipe, ksh, status

The following Command-line gives Exit Status for `tee` command. How do I get the return value of `make` in the following command-line

```
$ make -f Makefile_64bit 2>&1 | tee -a logfile  
$ echo $?
```

Comment: You can run the make again and it will be quite fast to finish the second time. Another solution is to use the logfile.

Comment: Running Make a second time is a crude solution, especially when make of the overall modules takes about 4+ hours to build :-), I have a requirement where the output has to be seen on the screen as well as it Make output needs to be there in the logfile as well.

Comment: When compilation is successful the first time, the rerun should be less than a minute. If it fails the first time, it should be very quick to fail at the very same step :) so my solution is not Elegant. Yet it is a workaround :)

Comment: Yes, I do agree with your comment, once the targets are built, the second run should be quick (may be few seconds), I will adopt your solution if I don't get other `elegant` :-) ways of solving the issue... thanks.

Comment: You can find quite some answers for this question. I liked the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14285/57293 since that one doesn't use addiotionl file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks Walter, it is informative page and I liked the solution with bash (I can choose to convert my script from ksh to bash as an alternative).

Comment: See [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another)

Comment: I have been able to get this done `elegantly` by using the following command-line (using ksh):

`$ set -o pipefail
$ make -f Makefile_64bit 2>&1 | tee -a logfile  
$ echo $?
1`

Thanks a lot for your help Krassi, Walter and agc

Comment: Ok @Anupum, please post your solution as an answer and accept it, so others will see the solution in one view.